# Proving a bounded function to be Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis

I am solving the following analysis problem.

Define $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$  f(x) = \begin{cases}
1  ,&  \text{if $1-2^{-2k} \leq x \leq 1-2^{-(2k+1) }$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$}  \\ 
0  ,&  \text{if $1-2^{-(2k+1)} \lt x \lt 1-2^{-(2k+2)}$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots$}\\
0  ,&  \text{if $x=1$}\end{cases} \text{.}  $$

Prove that $f$ is integrable on $[0, 1]$, and compute $$\int_{0}^1 f(x)dx.$$

My strategy is to sum up the values with a geometric series. Once I have it I want to pick an epsilon and work with the upper sum and lower sum until I have that

$$L(f) \leq U(f)$$ such that for any $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists a partition P such that $$L(p,f) -U(p,f) \lt \epsilon$$

work is as follows:

$$L(p,f)=\sum_{i=0}^N inf*(t_k-t_{k-1})$$
$$U(p,f)=\sum_{i=0}^N sup*(t_k-t_{k-1})$$
$x_i$=$1-2^I$ for $i=0,1,...,N+1$

when $i =0$ $inf=1$

when $i=1$ $inf=0$

when $i=2$ $inf=1$

For the upper and lower sum I have:
$$L(p,f)=0+\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} 1_ieven*2^{-i-1}=0+2^{-1}+2^{-3}+...$$
$$U(p,f)=2^{-N-1}+\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} 1_ieven*2^{-i-1}=2^{-N-1}+2^{-1}+2^{-3}...$$

Now, I think my proof up to this point is sound but Im having a hard time computing the sum at the very bottom and could use some help. thanks.